# Is there a macro to define the max amount of register that a particular Kernel can use?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

I wrote a CUDA library, is there anyway to specifically put a register cap on certain library kernel instead of put a register cap on all kernels within the library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the C code level there is not. You can use the `__launch_bounds__` keyword to specify the expected upper limit for threads per block, which can result in an upper register per thread limit during the compilation cycle. Alternatively, if you compile to PTX, you can introduce the `.maxnreg` to the kernel preamble.

CUDA 5 now supports separate compilation and has a device code linker, so it should also be possible to compile kernels to different device object files using different compiler arguments and then link them into your library object.

Comment: Thanks, so the `__launch_bounds__` keyword has the side-effect of putting an upper limit of the maximum reg can be used per thread? (which is equal to the `TOTAL_NUM_REG/(MAX_THREADS_PER_BLOCK * MAX_THREADS_PER_SM`), I guess?)

Comment: @user0002128: yes that is the intention. Whether it works that way or not might depend on which version of the compiler you use